# ¿Cómo editar CSS de un id que fue creado por un script?

Tags: javascript, css, botón, id

Tengo una etiqueta script que me genera el siguiente botón en la página.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El botón debería estar sin esa barra debajo y debería tener un tamaño de texto de 12 px (En vez de eso se genera con 15px).

Miré en el inspector de elementos y veo que se genera con un id "short-message" el cual quiero editar para cambiar el texto a 12px. La cuestión es ¿cómo puedo hacer eso?

He tratado cambiando el .css y He tratado de cambiar es estilo del id con Javascript y nada.

Comment: Es mejor en el .css, pero tendrías que ver si solo es ese elemento, ya que a veces los estilos los heredan del componente padre en donde se alojan

Comment: Buen punto, voy a revisar

Comment: Por favor, comparte tu código para que algún compañero pueda ayudarte de la mejor manera posible.

Answer (score 0):

Hola Deivis yo que tu colocare el css  `overflow: hidden;` a ese ID, y con respecto al tamaño verifica el padding ya que puede ser quien te este forzando a 15px o en su defecto puedes usar la etiqueta `max-width: 12px !important` y listo.

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente lo que ocurre es que,
el elemento se genera desde un evento externo a tu sitio,
entonces, cuando se carga el css, el elemento ahun no existe en tu sitio, por lo cual nunca se carga el estilo.
algo que puedes intentar hacer utilizando jquery

```
por medio de el selector document intenta hacer una funcion cuando se carge la vista esto puede intenta usando load o ready. 
$(document).load(function(){
    $(#short-message).css('font-size', '12px');
})
```